# Moving a question from Stack Overflow to the Code Review site

Tags: support, migration

Can I move a question from Stack Overflow to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? What will happen to the reputation earned for the OP and others who earned points for that question?

Answer (score 4):

You can flag the question for moderator attention and suggest that it be moved. Please only do this if there's a *very* good reason to do so, however. Most good code review questions can be answered (and often *are* answered) on Stack Overflow, and if the asker and answerer preferred to ask and answer here you should respect their wishes. If the question *isn't* very good, then moving it would be rude.

If there's a really good reason to migrate *and* you communicate this via a flag *and* the question is migrated, then all points earned here will be lost, while a roughly equivalent amount of reputation will be granted the authors on Code Review (*if* they decide to sign in there). Reputation earned from suggested edits is just lost.

### See also:

- [**A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)
- [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)
- [Should the question looking for help reducing if statements be migrated to Code Review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262558/should-the-question-looking-for-help-reducing-if-statements-be-migrated-to-code)
- [Declined flags which report a move to Code review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262565/declined-flags-which-report-a-move-to-code-review)